# EF Core executing stored procedure with null reference

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0

Executing a stored procedure creates this error with EF Core 2.0. I am beside myself with this error. Any pointers?

```
public class SalesDTO :  BaseEntity
{
    public int SalesID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public string SalesRep { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Sales Date")]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Sale Center")]
    public string CenterName { get; set; }
    public int CenterID { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public SalesType SalesType { get; set; }
}
```

Model class for the stored procedure.

This is my implementation class

```
public IEnumerable<SalesDTO> GetSales(int centerID, string user)
{
        string salesRep = user ?? "";

        List<SqlParameter> parms = new List<SqlParameter>
        {
            new SqlParameter("@CenterID", centerID),
            new SqlParameter("@SalesRep", salesRep)
        };

        return DataContext.Set<SalesDTO>().FromSql("spSalesList @CenterID, @SalesRep", parms.ToArray())
                 .Select(x => new SalesDTO
                 {
                     Id = x.SalesID,
                     SalesID = x.SalesID,
                     CustomerID = x.CustomerID,
                     CustomerName = x.CustomerName,
                     SalesType = x.SalesType,
                     TotalAmount = x.TotalAmount,
                     SalesRep = x.SalesRep,
                     CenterName = x.CenterName,
                     OrderDate = x.OrderDate,
                     CenterID = x.CenterID
                 }).AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }
```

This code throws:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

with this stack trace

[image: Stack Trace]

However, if I use SQL Server profiler, I can see that the stored procedure successfully executes when I copy what was executed back to SQL Server Management Studio and execute it.

Comment: Did you debug the code ? Did you check if DataContext is not null?

Comment: Yes, have debugged severally, DataContext is not null, repository is not null.

Comment: How about `Set<SalesDTO>()`? Does it return null? `SalesDTO` mapped to any table or return types stored proc?

Comment: SalesDTO is a poco class to represent the data structure of the stored procedure. It is defined on the DataContext as well.
public DbSet<SalesDTO> SalesDTO { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that the repository works alright it's just the data resolution.

If you use one property in the .Select to match to 2 different properties, the NULL Reference error is generated.
So this

```
return DataContext.Set<SalesDTO>().FromSql("spSalesList @CenterID, @SalesRep, @DateFrom, @DateTo", parms.ToArray())
                 .Select(x => new SalesDTO
                 {
                     Id = x.SalesID,
                     SalesID = x.SalesID,
                     CustomerID = x.CustomerID,
                     CustomerName = x.CustomerName,
                     SalesType = x.SalesType,
                     TotalAmount = x.TotalAmount,
                     SalesRep = x.SalesRep,
                     CenterName = x.CenterName,
                     OrderDate = x.OrderDate,
                     CenterID = x.CenterID
                 }).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

will give a Null Reference error because the SalesID is matched to both the SalesID column as well as the Id Column, though it may be the same field.
When you however change the code to

```
return DataContext.Set<SalesDTO>().FromSql("spSalesList @CenterID, @SalesRep, @DateFrom, @DateTo", parms.ToArray())
                 .Select(x => new SalesDTO
                 {
                     Id = x.Id,
                     SalesID = x.SalesID,
                     CustomerID = x.CustomerID,
                     CustomerName = x.CustomerName,
                     SalesType = x.SalesType,
                     TotalAmount = x.TotalAmount,
                     SalesRep = x.SalesRep,
                     CenterName = x.CenterName,
                     OrderDate = x.OrderDate,
                     CenterID = x.CenterID
                 }).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Then it works correctly since the Id and SalesID matches to different fields. I am yet to understand why that is so.
I will add a comment when i get to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below code, please.

```
return DataContext.Set<SalesDTO>().FromSql($"EXECUTE spSalesList {centerID} {salesRep}")
             .Select(x => new SalesDTO
             {
                 Id = x.SalesID,
                 SalesID = x.SalesID,
                 CustomerID = x.CustomerID,
                 CustomerName = x.CustomerName,
                 SalesType = x.SalesType,
                 TotalAmount = x.TotalAmount,
                 SalesRep = x.SalesRep,
                 CenterName = x.CenterName,
                 OrderDate = x.OrderDate,
                 CenterID = x.CenterID
             }).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Meanwhile, it's worthwhile to know the limitations:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#limitations

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, it produces the same error. Have checked the limitations and maybe something is escaping me. In the mean time i have changed to use the ViewModel directly instead of a stored procedure until am able to figure out why the error keeps coming back. Will add my findings when i do